# Is there a warning for assigning an enum variable with a value out of the range of the enum?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I have a C function which uses an `enum` as parameter, like the example bellow:

```
typedef enum
{
  AB, 
  CD
} A;

void f(A input)
{
  // do something
}

int main(void)
{
   // do something
   f(-10);
   // do something
}
```

Is there a warning that I can enable for assigning an enum variable with a value out of the range of the enum?

Comment: Clang provides a warning with `-Wassign-enum`.

Comment: thanks @EricPostpischil, but I am using GCC so this does not apply

Comment: My spontaneus thought is that if you pass an invalid value in this situation, there's something SERIOUSLY wrong with your design...

Comment: it is an user API, and hence I cannot control what the user will do with it. Of course, I can control the parameter in the function body. I am looking for a way to prevent it at compilation level

Answer (score 9):

There is an [open bug for it](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67314) in the GCC bug database.  It seems that GCC does not contain such a feature yet. There is an option called `-Wc++-compat` which would complain - among myriad other things, about *any* integer being converted implicitly to an enum type.

A related feature has *just* landed into the GCC repository.
In GCC trunk (but not in 9.2.1 which is the compiler of Ubuntu 19.10), there is a switch `-Wenum-conversion`, which would warn about the use of an unrelated enum value, but not a bare integer; i.e. with the code below [it will warn about the *latter* function call, but not the former.](https://godbolt.org/z/2GyNyz):

```
typedef enum{ AB, CD } A;

typedef enum{ EF, GH } B;

void f(A input){
    (void)input;
}

int main(void){
    f(-10);
    f(GH);
}
```

The diagnostics from compiling with `-Wenum-conversion` would be

```
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:18:6: warning: implicit conversion from 'enum <anonymous>' to 'A' [-Wenum-conversion]
   18 |    f(GH);
      |      ^~
```

Comment: Yes Antti, usage of two different enums are easy to catch. My question is regarding capturing cases where I use one enum, and the parameter is not the defined enum, but a given integer (out of the defined enum range)

Comment: @FelipeGM Usage of two different enums is *not* easy to catch at all without compiler support. The main takeaway here was that even *that* was just implemented in GCC.

Comment: My bad Antti, my point is that it is easy to catch WITH compiler support

Comment: There is no 9.2.1 GCC, that's just the distro patching some "bugs".

Answer (score 2):

Even if `enum` is a user defined type, it is translated by the compiler as a primitive, in my case `int`, you can check it using:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define printHelloIfEnumIsInt(x) \
    _Generic(x, int: puts("Hello"));

typedef enum {
  AB, 
  CD
} A;

int main(void)
{
    printHelloIfEnumIsInt(AB);
    return 0;
}
```

returns:

```
Hello
```

so any value in the range of `INT_MIN` ... `INT_MAX` is allowed.

Comment: exactly my point David! It is translated to integer, which shades the capture of the out of the range problem. I was wondering if there wasn't a flag to capture it before it happens

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any good way of doing it. But, provided that you do not use any `=` in your enum like `enum foo {a=0, b=4}`, you can do like this:

```
typedef enum{
  AB, 
  CD,
  A_max // Extra field that should be last
} A;

void f(A input){
    assert(input >= 0 && input < A_max);
    //  Do something
}
```

This works, because if no `=` is used, the first element will be zero, and all the following will add 1 for each of them.

Comment: yes klutt, at the function body one can assert the input and ensure it will be within range. I was wondering if GCC didn't have any prevention at compilation level, as G++ or Clang do